# react-native run-ios does not launch app

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

Whenever I run `react-native run-ios` it hangs after loading the simulator and outputting

```
Scanning 585 folders for symlinks in /Users/myname/Documents/Code/pma-game/node_modules (13ms)
Found Xcode workspace PMAGame.xcworkspace
Launching iPhone 6 (iOS 10.3)...
Building using "xcodebuild -workspace PMAGame.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme PMAGame -destination id=3E2D26A0-B0FA-449C-B87C-EFB6BF2F25F1 -derivedDataPath build"
User defaults from command line:

    IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/myname/Documents/Code/pma-game/ios/build
```

I've tried restarting, but have had no success. I've also tried reinstalling react-native and watchman.

Comment: what was your workaround? please share, stuck in the same problem.. :(