# Build Hangs While Running 'react-native run-ios'

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, build

I am stuck on a problem. While running commnand from cli `react-native run-ios`

```
Found Xcode project myproject.xcodeproj
Launching iPhone 6 (iOS 10.3)...
Building using "xcodebuild -project myproject.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -scheme myproject -destination id=CB73A374-3E21-4C73-BEC4-AD29A583FCE8 -derivedDataPath build"
User defaults from command line:

IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/.../myproject/ios/build
```

It just hangs and then nothing happens, no response.

I already checked an earlier [question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433034/react-native-run-ios-does-not-launch-app) and [issue in github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9821), but got no help. I may have asked a duplicate question but I am in badly need of a solution. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Any luck with this? Unfortunately, none of the options below help...

Comment: Anyone has answer?

Comment: Well I bypassed the problem by building from xcode

Answer (score 5):

I know this is way later than the question was asked, but since it was never answered, I wanted to throw this up here cause it just happened to me.

I got past that by doing `rm -rf node_modules/` and then doing `npm install`.

Hope this helps someone else in the future as well! :-D

Comment: Yes, it helped me! Thank you

Comment: Anyone has answer?

Answer (score 2):

This resolved the problem for me, Under project.workspace, there is a file called "contents.xcworkspacedata".(This can be opened from your IDE)
There was a duplication of the fileref tag, removed one and ran react-native run-ios, and it worked.

```
<FileRef
      location = "group:project.xcodeproj">
   </FileRef>
```

Answer (score 2):

For someone stuck on it in 2023, for me just trying to start a React Native project following their documentation did not work.

My Mac is M1, which caused a lot of different issues. Eventually, I solved it by:

1. Making sure my ruby version was correct. I used a combination of `arch -arm64 rvm install 2.7.6` (The version being latest Ruby version required on boilerplate React Native project). Then to use the version, `rvm use 2.7.6`. I then initiated my React Native project using `arch -arm64 npx react-native init <ProjectName>`. Rest of the commands such as `npx react-native run-ios` worked as usual.
2. Moving the project away from iCloud Drive folder fixed it from being stuck on "Building the app..." (Still takes a while to build).

I spent my weekend trying to solve this. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

- close your IDE
- run in a terminal:

```
sudo kill -9 `ps aux | grep node | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
```

- Re-open your IDE
- re-run: (npx) react-native run-ios